# Linux command line/app to compare sets of folders against one another

Tags: linux, command-line, file-management

I have many photos organised in folders. I also have an "Uncategorised" folder for photos before they are organised. I've found that many (but not all) photos in Uncategorised have now been organised away, but not removed from Uncategorised.

I would like, via command line or otherwise, to find all files in Uncategorised that are duplicated within other folders (so I know which are safe to delete).  Ideally the solution will use MD5 (or similar) to ensure true duplication.  However, file name -only is a good start.

Can anyone provide some hint of how to accomplish this on the command line? Or alternatively suggest some software that could help?

Thanks!

Comment: Linux offers **md5sum** or variety of sha1sum,sha256,384,sha512sum options.  Do you need help using the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
find -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | uniq -d | xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate
```

(replace md5sum with sha512sum to avoid collisions)

or a "lint" tool like fslint, fdupes